# Filling a JList with data

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, jlist

Does anyone have any good tutorials on how to fill a `JList` (within a `JPanel`) with user inputted data. Specifically, I want to add people to a selected roster. Is this a matter of filling it with an `ArrayList`?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It should generally be `JList` -> **`JScrollPane`** -> `JPanel`.

Comment: @TopChef question about `..with user inputted data`, are you look for editable JList contents ???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- create a ListModel which wrapps your java.util.List (e.g. by extending AbstractListModel)
- configure JList to use this model
- create and configure a renderer to format/ display the Objects in your list as needed

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html

Comment: +1, for being the first to link to the Swing tutorial which has a working example that does exactly what the OP wants to do.

Comment: Well, somebody else was first, but that response seems to be removed... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You create a `JList` with a `ListModel`. When you edit your `ListModel`, it is reflected on `JList` as well.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is having a little bit time with Google. I find the following results with Google.

- [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)
- [Customize Your JList Display](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/jlist/)
- [Basic Swing components II](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javaswingtutorial/basicswingcomponentsII/)
- [JLists, Data Models, and Cell Renderers](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Swing-Tutorial/Swing-Tutorial-JList.html)

Answer (score -1):

Use any layout manager like [Gridlayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html).