# How to display an ArrayList using Swing?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jtable, jlist

I have two `ArrayList` instances that contain some data and I want that data to be displayed as boxes or their data by using Swing.

The end goal is to display both array lists as one matrix of junctions and roads.

I have an object that contains both:

```
    Map map = new Map(10);
    System.out.println(map.calcShortestPath(map.getJunctions().get(4), map.getJunctions().get(0)));

    System.out.println("\n Map #2");
    ArrayList<Junction> junctions = new ArrayList<Junction>();
    junctions.add(new Junction(0, 0));
    junctions.add(new Junction(0, 3));
    junctions.add(new Junction(4, 3));
    junctions.add(new Junction(4, 0));

    ArrayList<Road> roads = new ArrayList<Road>();
    roads.add(new Road(junctions.get(0), junctions.get(1)));
    roads.add(new Road(junctions.get(1), junctions.get(2)));
    roads.add(new Road(junctions.get(2), junctions.get(3)));
    roads.add(new Road(junctions.get(3), junctions.get(0)));
    roads.add(new Road(junctions.get(0), junctions.get(2)));
    map = new Map(junctions, roads);
```

The things I have tried so far:

- Using `JTable` - didn't seem to be the correct choice for this.
- Using `JList` - didn't seem to work as I tried to see one of the lists with this
  code:

  ```
    JList<Juncion> displayList = new JList<>(junctions.toArray(new String[0]));
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(displayList);

    getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
  ```

I think I'm getting closer to this by using the `JList` but I think I'm not doing this the correct way.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Show us the attempt using a `JList` (though I'm not yet sure what is the best component / components). Do you have an image (or drawing) of how the GUI should look? I'm particularly unclear on what *"one matrix of junctions and roads"* would look like on-screen.

Comment: Hi,if i had any minimal reproducible example i would have shared @AndrewThompson the problem is i myself don't know much about Jswing and the doc is not updated at all. the major thing i try to do now is atleast being able to see my ArrayList on the Frame but the only thing im able to see now is the blank frame.

Comment: *"if i had any minimal reproducible example .. he major thing i try to do now is atleast being able to see my ArrayList on the Frame but the only thing im able to see now is the blank frame."* So .. that. That could be a MRE. It should only take a handful of lines of code to reproduce the effect. We could take a look at it and perhaps spot the problem, if not, we can compile and run it to investigate further.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402205

Comment: @Puce its not really a duplicate as their isn't a clear answer and nor is the question clear in that post.

Comment: You've defined a graph.  Your junctions are vertexes and your roads are edges.  You're going to have to draw the graph on a JPanel.  The Oracle tutorial [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) shows you how to draw on a JPanel.

Answer (score 2):

I thought it might be interesting to whip up an example of a graph display.

Here's the GUI I created.

[image: Graph Display GUI]

The junctions are represented by squares, and the roads are represented by lines.

The first thing I did was create a `Graph` class to hold a `List` of junctions and a `List` of roads.  I had to guess what the numbers of the `Junction` class represented.  I assumed they were X and Y coordinates.

Once I created the `Graph` class (model class), writing the drawing panel and the `paintComponent` method was straightforward.

Here's the code.  You would need to modify it to display more than one graph.

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GraphDisplay implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new GraphDisplay());
    }

    private DrawingPanel drawingPanel;

    private Graph graph;

    private JFrame frame;

    public GraphDisplay() {
        this.graph = new Graph();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame("Graph Display");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel(graph);
        frame.add(drawingPanel);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private Graph graph;

        private Tuple xTuple;
        private Tuple yTuple;

        public DrawingPanel(Graph graph) {
            this.graph = graph;
            this.xTuple = graph.getXRange();
            this.yTuple = graph.getYRange();

            this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            int xSpacing = getWidth() / (xTuple.getMaximum() -
                    xTuple.getMinimum() + 2);
            int ySpacing = getHeight() / (yTuple.getMaximum() -
                    yTuple.getMinimum() + 2);

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5f));

            Font font = getFont().deriveFont(16f);
            g2d.setFont(font);

            List<Junction> junctions = graph.getJunctions();
            for (int i = 0; i < junctions.size(); i++) {
                Junction junction = junctions.get(i);
                int x = (junction.getX() + 1) * xSpacing;
                int y = (junction.getY() + 1) * ySpacing;
                g.drawRect(x - 16, y - 16, 32, 32);
            }

            List<Road> roads = graph.getRoads();
            for (int i = 0; i < roads.size(); i++) {
                Road road = roads.get(i);
                Junction origin = road.getOrigin();
                Junction destination = road.getDestination();

                int x1 = (origin.getX() + 1) * xSpacing;
                int y1 = (origin.getY() + 1) * ySpacing;
                int x2 = (destination.getX() + 1) * xSpacing;
                int y2 = (destination.getY() + 1) * ySpacing;

                g2d.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
            }
        }

    }

    public class Graph {

        private final List<Junction> junctions;

        private final List<Road> roads;

        public Graph() {
            junctions = new ArrayList<Junction>();
            junctions.add(new Junction(0, 0));
            junctions.add(new Junction(0, 3));
            junctions.add(new Junction(4, 3));
            junctions.add(new Junction(4, 0));

            roads = new ArrayList<Road>();
            roads.add(new Road(junctions.get(0), junctions.get(1)));
            roads.add(new Road(junctions.get(1), junctions.get(2)));
            roads.add(new Road(junctions.get(2), junctions.get(3)));
            roads.add(new Road(junctions.get(3), junctions.get(0)));
            roads.add(new Road(junctions.get(0), junctions.get(2)));
        }

        public List<Junction> getJunctions() {
            return junctions;
        }

        public List<Road> getRoads() {
            return roads;
        }

        public Tuple getXRange() {
            int minimum = junctions.get(0).getX();
            int maximum = minimum;

            for (int i = 1; i < junctions.size(); i++) {
                int x = junctions.get(i).getX();
                minimum = Math.min(minimum, x);
                maximum = Math.max(maximum, x);
            }

            return new Tuple(minimum, maximum);
        }

        public Tuple getYRange() {
            int minimum = junctions.get(0).getY();
            int maximum = minimum;

            for (int i = 1; i < junctions.size(); i++) {
                int y = junctions.get(i).getY();
                minimum = Math.min(minimum, y);
                maximum = Math.max(maximum, y);
            }

            return new Tuple(minimum, maximum);
        }

    }

    public class Road {

        private final Junction origin;
        private final Junction destination;

        public Road(Junction origin, Junction destination) {
            this.origin = origin;
            this.destination = destination;
        }

        public Junction getOrigin() {
            return origin;
        }

        public Junction getDestination() {
            return destination;
        }

    }

    public class Junction {

        private final int x;
        private final int y;

        public Junction(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public int getX() {
            return x;
        }

        public int getY() {
            return y;
        }

    }

    public class Tuple {

        private final int minimum;
        private final int maximum;

        public Tuple(int minimum, int maximum) {
            this.minimum = minimum;
            this.maximum = maximum;
        }

        public int getMinimum() {
            return minimum;
        }

        public int getMaximum() {
            return maximum;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Windows? Alt+Print Screen will do a screenshot of the current app. only.